One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified - @triniwiz/nativescript-downloader - AndroidSDK 34
I use @triniwiz/nativescript-downloader@3.0.1 in my application.
Since yesterday I can't run the app it because during the initialization I get this error:
One of RECEIVER_EXPORTED or RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED should be specified when a receiver isn't being registered exclusively for system broadcasts
It's traceable to the point I first use the Downloader.
I've put this line but it doesn't help:
Application.android.registerBroadcastReceiver('RECEIVER_EXPORTED', (context, intent) => {});
How I can properly register the broadcast and fix this issue?
